# Is an MVD with a CK as determinant actually a FD?

Tags: database-design, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Is a [multivalued dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency) A ->> B, A ->> C where A is a [candidate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key) a [functional dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency)?

I would think so, since A being a candidate key implies that for every value a of A, the values of B and C are uniquely determined...

Comment: "X ->> Y, X ->> Z" is not a MVD, it is two MVDs separated by a comma. Maybe you mean "X ->> Y | Z", but that isn't a MVD either, although it implies X ->> Y & X ->> Z. Do you mean, "if A ->> B | C ..."? Or "if A ->> B ..." ? Or "if A ->> B and A ->> C ..."? Or what?

Comment: @philipxy I am new to database design so I do not know the widespread conventions. However, the book I am using in my class is [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/Database-Systems-Practical-Implementation-Management/dp/0132943263/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1507181197&sr=8-1&keywords=database+systems+connolly+6th+edition) and in Chapter 15 (titled Advanced Normalization) of that book, Section 15.4.1 (titled Multi-Valued Dependency), it is written "We represent a MVD between attributes A, B et C in a relation using the following notation : A ->> B (on one line) A ->> C (on another line)"

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I don't object to using MVD as a constraint/condition. In sentences your textbook uses 1 arrow per MVD. Seems they stacked MVDs to show two ways to express the the same MVD/condition. (Both expressions do denote the same condition.) (Since X -> Y & X -> (all - Y) denote the same condition.) But even with "MVD" as constraint/condition, hence accepting A ->> B|C (standard notation) as "a" MVD, A -> B & A -> C are *different* FDs--so according to your own interpretation your question doesn't make sense when it asks if the MVD is "a" FD. What FD?

Comment: @philipxy Oh, you think the author meant that A ->> B **or** A ->> C can be used to denote a MVD? If so, it is poorly written, in my opinion. I thought one should normally write both arrows because, in the treatment in the book, nowhere does it say that C has to be the set of all attributes -
 (A+B). I thought the author used only one arrow in sentences because C was understood or unimportant for the current purposes. Seems like I got everything wrong then. Anyway, to answer your question, I was thinking about the FD "A -> B,C".

Comment: The `|` does not mean `or` or `union`, it is just a piece of syntax that along with `->>` is used via `x->>y|z` to say that 2 MVDs `x->>y` & `x->>z` both hold, in a context where they say the same thing (imply each other).

Answer (score 2):

FDs (functional dependencies) & MVDs (multivalued dependencies) are *expressions*. So nothing is both a FD & a MVD. `X ↠ Y, X ↠ Z` is not a MVD; it is two MVDs separated by a comma. We could write that as part of a formal derivation, but that's not what you're doing. `X ↠ Y | Z` isn't a MVD, although it implies `X ↠ Y` & `X ↠ Z`. (And it is normally limited to use when Z is the set of all attributes less X+Y).) So even it doesn't make sense to talk about "the" FD (functional dependency) associated with `X ↠ Y | Z`. We could talk about "the" *constraint* or *condition* expressed by a FD, MVD or `|` expression. (Which you seem to have some idea of since you talk about "a" MVD & "a" FD.) But a FD constraint wouldn't "be" a different constraint just because some other stuff was true, like A being a CK. However, we can speak about what things hold when other things hold in terms of FDs, MVDs & `|` expressions.

So let's use terminology correctly:

Q: If A ↠ B | C and A is a CK (candidate key), is it the case that A → B & A → C?
A: Since a CK determines every set of attributes, A → B & A → C.

Or more simply,

Q: If A ↠ B and A is a CK (candidate key), is it the case that A → B?
A: Since a CK determines every attribute set, A → B.

Comment: You say that nothing is both a FD and a MVD, but on the [Wikipedia article about MVDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency) it is written that "Every FD is an MVD" ?

Comment: Yes, but it's wrong. It's a very common misconception. Use textbooks not wikipedia. Even then many texbooks are sloppy. I'll look at yours. Notice that X ->> Y can hold when X -> Y doesn't, so even as constraints they don't say the same thing. A FD *implies* a certain MVD. (In the case of MVDs & JDs, each MVD holds if & only if a certain JD holds, so it's reasonable to say they "are" the same constraint, although different expresssions.) Use technical terms precisely. Read my answer.

Comment: Your text mostly treats a FD as a "constraint/"condition", and we do also normally speak this way, not bothering to distinguish between the [expression](http://webdam.inria.fr/Alice/pdfs/Chapter-8.pdf) & its constraint. Reading (4th ed of) your textbook...ugh, both poor & nonstandard re MVDs. Eg MVDs pair *sets* of attributes. Eg the boxed definition of MVD is so informal it's *litereally* nonsense. (It means neither  that for A -> B|C the projections on AB & AC join back to the original nor that every AB subrow value with a given A must appear with every AC subrow value with that A.)

Comment: I've read a few chapters up till now and, yeah, I'm glad to know I'm not the only one who finds its informality disconcerting. Not only that: at Section 15.1.2, for example, they write they now introduce equivalence of sets of functional dependencies... but they never define that! Incredible.